# Django - How would I apply CSS for a radio model formset?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, formset

I want to customize a radio form in Django, but because of the way that the `formset` is rendered by Django, where I'm not able to manipulate `{{ field }}` properties to manually render the form due to the behavior of formsets, I'm unable to customize it properly.

If I apply

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.html_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The names and ids are generated in a way that doesn't allow me to freely manipulate how the data is passed back into Django.

The CSS rules that I've been using assume that the `<input>` tag and the `<label>` tag are next to each other, but the way that Django renders the form has the `<input>` tag inside of the `<label>` tag. These are the CSS rules that I'm applying, with the HTML

```css
[type="radio"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label
{ 
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
     display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f0c8"; /* Unicode for Font Awesome icons */
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f0c8"; /* Unicode for Font Awesome icons */
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before, input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f14a";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Yes</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">No</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

While the HTML that's generated by Django is:

```html
<input name="model_set-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_model_set-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden"><input name="model_set-INITIAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_model_set-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden">
<input name="model_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_model_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden">
<input name="model_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_model_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden">
<ul id="id_model_set-0-field" class="regular-radio">
  <li>
    <label for="id_model_set-0_field_0" style="color: black;">
      <input name="model_set-0-field" value="1" class="regular-radio" id="id_model_set-0_field_0" autocomplete="off" required="required" type="radio">
      Yes
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_model_set-0_field_1" style="color: black;">
      <input name="model_set-0-field" value="0" class="regular-radio" id="id_model_set-0_field_1" autocomplete="off" required="required" type="radio">
      No
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<input name="model_set-0-id" value="1" id="id_model_set-0-id" type="hidden">
<input name="model_set-0-parentmodel" value="1" id="id_model_set-0-parentmodel" type="hidden">
<ul id="id_model_set-1-field" class="regular-radio">
  <li>
    <label for="id_model_set-1_field_0" style="color: black;">
    <input name="model_set-1-field" value="1" class="regular-radio" id="id_model_set-1_field_0" autocomplete="off" required="required" type="radio">
    Yes
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_model_set-1_field_1" style="color: black;">
      <input name="model_set-1-field" value="0" class="regular-radio" id="id_model_set-1_field_1" autocomplete="off" required="required" type="radio">
    No
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<input name="model_set-1-id" value="2" id="id_model_set-1-id" type="hidden">
<input name="model_set-1-pico_values" value="1" id="id_model_set-1-parentmodel" type="hidden">
```

This is how I'm rendering the formset in Django:

```
<li class="list-group-item outline">
    <div class="col">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</li>
```

How would I go about applying the css rules I want to this rendered template?

Comment: The answers in that question show how individual fields in forms can be rendered without using {{ form }} , {{ form.a_p }} etc. You can tweak the html in those answers to give te required layout